# Highcharts keep scaling when add values dynamiclly

Tags: highcharts

I am tired of one issue which I faced with few days ago and still do not solve it. I have a Highstock chart with two series:

```
{
    rangeSelector: {
      buttons: [{
        type: 'day',
        count: 1,
        text: '1d'
      }, {
        type: 'week',
        count: 1,
        text: '1W'
      }, {
        type: 'month',
        count: 1,
        text: '1M'
      }, {
        type: 'all',
        count: 1,
        text: 'All'
      }],
      selected: 1,
      inputEnabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      useHTML: Highstock.hasBidiBug
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'MAX',
        data: this.chartData.maxValuesArr
      },
      {
        name: 'MIN',
        data: this.chartData.minValuesArr
      }]
  }
```

As you can see I use range for a one week by default, I got from BE array with 1600 values since 2014 year and it scales good and shows me the last week by default, but, also I have prices updates every 30(more/less) seconds, I have tried a lot of ways to add those values in such way that dont break the scale of the chart! [On the picture you can see that 18 of jule is bigger than other days and all it became like that because I added updated point to it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJWaX.png)

The question is how can I add(update) chart dynamically and dont break the scale. For range I use buttons(see config) thats why I cannot use `chart.setExtremes()`

I ll be very thankful!

Comment: Have you tried setting `xAxis.ordinal` to `false`? **API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Comment: @KamilKulig, dude, God`s bless you and your family, I have spend 3 days of looking for the solutions!!!!